# trying to isolate a block from my logs with awk, help please!

Tags: awk

I am trying to write an awk script that can get a block that contains the word "error", out of a long log file.

Basically this log file contains actions performed, and when one of these fails, it will add under the action the error line, saying what is wrong.

I can isolate easily the error line just doing a grep for "error:", but i am missing the command given since it is printed before the error line, and i do not know how many lines before, so cannot just arbitrarily say "print the 10 lines that precede the word "error:"

I've figured out a sort of scheme thou; each of the block that could contain the error lines starts in the same way ("ProcessName"), followed by the command and other parameters, each one on a different line, and the last line will always be an empty line.

So my idea is to use this block with awk, so i can look for the "processName" string, start to print the lines one by one until i reach the empty line, and then pipe the printed result trough a grep to see if there is the word "error:" in there; if there is an error then i will redirect on a file and append the whole block, otherwise it will continue to the next block and do the same thing.

Now it would really help if i can get a hand with this task; since I do not really know how could I achieve this; I've just looked at awk and it seems to be the right tool for the job (i can write a shell script for the task), but if you think that there is a better way to do it in a shell script, I am all ears :)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Update: Thanks for your scripts; i've got the one from Dennis to work but it prints the same block more than once, if there is more than one error entry in each block; while the example from bellisarius does not return any line.

I've added an example of what my log looks like, when i introduce an error (there is an empty line at the end, but cannot add it if i put the text in the tag code):

```
ProcessName
ID=1231
Command:"ls -l a"
Hash "gkfsmgflsdmgklsdmfldsmfklmdsflkmsdflmsdflkmsdflkmsdfklsdmfklsdmfklmsdfklmsdklfmsdklmflksdmflkdsmfkldsmfkldmslfmdslkfmklsdmflksdmfklsdmfkldmslfkmslfkmsdlkfm"
/filename/compileme.c:20: error: the directory does not exist
/filename/compileme.c:20: error: incorrect parameter
```

A regular block looks exactly the same, but does not have the error: part obviously.

Hope that this makes it more clear, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
BEGIN                {flag="no";k=0}

/ProcessName/        {flag="no";k=0}

/ProcessName/,/^$/   {a[k++]=$0; 
                     if(match($0,"error")!= 0) {flag="yes"};
                     }

/^$/                 {if (flag=="yes") {flag="no"; 
                                       for ( i=0; i<k; i++ ){print a[i]}
                                       print "-------";
                                      }; 
                     for ( r in a ){delete a[r]};k=0;
                     }
```

Test:

Input:

```
ProcessName
adasd
asdasd

ProcessName with err 
error  
salutti

ProcessName no err  
aaa
no err 

ProcessName
```

Output:

```
ProcessName with err 
error  
salutti

-------
```

[**Running at ideone here**](http://ideone.com/clone/QZrgd)

**Edit**

On your comment about having *sometimes* an empty record before the error record, you can solve that by pre-processing your log files with the following awk script that deletes the empty lines before the error messages:

```
/^$/ {getline; if($0 !~ /error/) print ""}  
{print}
```

and then running the main script on the output of this one.

Comment: I believe you need to use an incremented index into the array instead of using "in" or the array elements won't be in a defined order. You can do this to delete the whole array without having to iterate over it: `split("", a)` (in `gawk`: `delete a`).

Comment: You're deleting them after you print them. Deleting them won't affect the order they're printed. However, iterating using `in` to print them doesn't guarantee the order of output. From [`info gawk`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Scanning-an-Array.html#Scanning-an-Array): "The order in which elements of the array are accessed by this
statement is determined by the internal arrangement of the array
elements within `awk' and cannot be controlled or changed." ...

Comment: ... From [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html): "...which shall iterate, assigning each index of array to variable in an unspecified order."

Comment: Thanks Belisarius; I tried it and it seems to not print anything :(  I've added an example of my error log, so you see exactly how it is structured....probably I explained it wrong.

Comment: @newbiez Can't find your example. Where is it?

Comment: updated the main post; i cannot add code or format it in a comment. Thanks!

Comment: @Dennis code updated with your suggestions (I got a counter example of my previous believing)

Comment: Works Awesomely :) now I have noticed thou that sometimes i get an extra empty line right before the errors, which one is the part where you look for the empty line? I wanna try to modify your excellent script to cover also that case

Comment: @newbiez that changes the problem a lot! :( It isn't a simple mod, since the logic is based on empty lines or "ProcessName" splitting blocks. I'll try to think about it.

Comment: Sorry :( If i could ask the guys that makes the logs in this way i would love that they would make the logs easier to parse; sadly i had this error formatted in this way only now and i realized that if is more than one file that is failing, i get a space between each file that is failing, so my block logic won't work on these errors. I've tried to modify your example, but i hit the wall every time that i gotta tell awk that there are multiple files that could potentially have multiple "error:" strings :(  Thanks again for helping me with this! Is 3 days that i am fighting with the problem >_<

Comment: You rock belisarius :) BTW the pre-script has to have a space in between the quotes, otherwise it will add an extra line instead of removing it, and I have replaced "error" with "ProcessName", removing the NOT; now it is able to take out all the extra spaces for the edge cases! [Ideone_ex](http://ideone.com/GgpCD)

Comment: @newbiez just be careful, because " " does not match /^$/ (for the second stage)

Answer (score 0):

Next time, show some sample input

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}/ProcessName/ && /Error/' file


$ cat file
ProcessName
adasd
asdasd

ProcessName with err
error
salutti

ProcessName no err
aaa
no err

$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}/ProcessName/ && /err/' file
ProcessName with err
error
salutti
ProcessName no err
aaa
no err
```

Comment: That will print every line in the file.

Comment: I overlooked the specification that "the last line will always be an empty line".

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
awk '/ProcessName/{a = $0; next} {a = a RS $0} /error:/{print a}' inputfile
```

It accumulates lines and resets the accumulator each time it sees "ProcessName". When it sees "error:" it prints the contents of the accumulator.

Comment: If empty lines separates the blocks, there may be some blocks that doesn't have "ProcessName" but with "error:". Your solution may accidentally catch "error:" at the next block

Comment: Thanks Dennis; indeed when the block has more than one "error:" line it will print out the same error multiple times, for how many instances of "error:" are in the block

Answer (score 0):

for blank-line delimited files, I find Perl easiest:

```
perl -00 -ne 'print if /^ProcessName/ && /error/' afile
```

The `-00` option is the magic incantation to pass the file a paragraph at a time.