# Deleting Column Selection in AWK

Tags: awk

I'd like to delete a selection of columns from a list of CSV files. The awk call is in-line as it is used in a shell script. I don't know beforehand how many columns the files have, only that the columns that I want gone are included in each file of the list.

Let's say I want the first 4 columns removed. Blanking out the column values will leave the separators, which I also want gone.

I though the following would work: create an array of column numbers to drop, and recreate the corresponding row without those columns.

The value of length(row) below is as expected, but the final loop still iterates over the original column count, not the actual length(row) value.

head $f | awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";split("1,2,3,4",dropers,",")}{split($0,row,FS);for(i in dropers) delete row[i]; print NF "," length(row) "<<<";out=""; print NF "," length(row) ">>>";for(i=1;i<=length(row);i++){print row[i] "lulu"; out = out "," row[i]}; sub(/[ \t]*$/,"",out);print out}'  > $g

or formatted:

```
head $f | awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";split("1,2,3,4",dropers,",")}{split($0,row,FS);for(i in dropers) delete row[i]; print NF "," length(row) "<<<";out=""; print NF "," length(row) ">>>";for(i=1;i<=length(row);i++){print row[i] "lulu"; out = out "," row[i]}; sub(/[ \t]*$/,"",out);print out}'  > $g
```

Here's the output for 2 files: 6 columns going in, 2 left when I've deleted columns 1 through 4, yet the loop iterates over the full 6 cols rather than the expected 2. Thank you for any advice.

Aust.

```
6,2<<<
6,2>>>
lulu
lulu
lulu
lulu
0000009lulu
461474lulu
,,,,,0000009,461474
6,2<<<
6,2>>>
lulu
lulu
lulu
lulu
0000010lulu
94942lulu
,,,,,0000010,94942
```

**Edit** (Belisarius)
Formatted code follows:

```
BEGIN {FS=",";
       split("1,2,3,4",dropers,",")
      }

{ split($0,row,FS);
  for(i in dropers) delete row[i]; 
  print NF "," length(row) "<<<";
  out=""; 
  print NF "," length(row) ">>>";
  for(i=1;i<=length(row);i++){print row[i] "lulu"; 
                              out = out "," row[i]}; 
  sub(/[ \t]*$/,"",out);
  print out
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BEGIN {FS=",";
       split("1,2,3,4",dropers,",")
      }

{ split($0,row,FS);
  for(i in dropers) delete row[i]; 
  print NF "," length(row) "<<<";
  out=""; 
  print NF "," length(row) ">>>";
  for(i in row){print row[i] "lulu"; 
                out = out "," row[i]}; 
  out = substr(out,2)
  sub(/[ \t]*$/,"",out);
  print out
}
```

with input:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g
```

prints:

```
7,3<<<
7,3>>>
elulu
flulu
glulu
e,f,g
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And I get the substr(out,2) call. I'm still hazy on why the for(i in row) has less iterations than for(i=1;i<=length(row);i++).

Comment: @auduf that is because those are associative arrays!

Comment: How is it that if length(row)=2, the loop for(i=1;i<=length(row);i++) loops 6 times. I've read up on associative arrays, and the for(i in row) loop doesn't guarantee the indexed order, which means -to me at least- that the column order in the output might be different than that of the input. Am I seeing this right? Still searching, and appreciate your input, thanks belisarius.

Comment: @auduf Indeed. I made that mistake before, seems one never learn. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036787/trying-to-isolate-a-block-from-my-logs-with-awk-help-please/5037035#5037035, and the comments by Dennis there.